# Lightning web component calling Google geocode service in background

Tags: lightning-web-components, google, geocoding

I have created a lighting web component, I am using Google geocode service in it for getting Lat-long, To prevent for calling in each time on the page load I store that data in a custom object and this is working fine.

But its calling geocode service continuously without logging in the browser network, and google bill is shutting up.

I am using `@wire` call to getting data on page load and checking its lat-long is present or not in a custom object.

Logs are working fine. Only thing is LWC is calling Google to geocode service and I can't see in a network or in the console.

Please help.

```
googleAPICall = (address) => {
            if(!address.length){
             return false;  
             }
            const key = '****************************'; 
            const url =  `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${address}&key=${key}`
            console.log("calling google geocode service");
            return fetch(url, { method: "POST" })
                .then((data) => { return data.json() })
                .then((response) => {
                    return response;
                }).catch((e) => { 
                     console.log(e); 
                });    
    }
```

Note: With browser debugging, I got t know @wire is not working properly, adding null check prevented those calls still it's calling one or two calls in the background. I think it's related to lifecycles of LWC

Comment: Can you post some code snippets from the web component showing where and how you're making the API call?

Comment: You need to put your logic for getting the lat-long on Apex side so that it can be cached

Comment: Did you check the console for iFrames?

Comment: With browser debugging, I got t know `@wire` is not working properly, adding null check prevented those calls still it's calling one or two calls in the background. I think it's related to lifecycles of LWC.

Comment: can you add markup?